# getting and showing data from mysql in visual basic 2008

Tags: vb.net

how can i get data from mysql table and show it in listbox in visual basic 2008

mysql table

id 
filename varchar 255
filetime timestamp

and it is windows application

Comment: not even close to a real question...

Comment: What data? How do your table structures look like? What listbox? Web application? Windows application? Any sample code as to what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install driver for MySql and perform ADO.Net (with the connection string for connection to MySql Database) on your VB.Net code.